# Looping Smooth Spline Generation That Will Be Evaluated in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to generate a spline with smooth peaks and troughs. This spline will be evaluated. Once the object following the spline reaches the end of the spline, it returns to the beginning (loop, not ping pong), and a new spline (generated spline 2) with the same start and end points is generated, however, it has different peaks and troughs. How could one achieve this effect in animation nodes?

[image]

Comment: You can use BAN if that is your preference.  In addition you might find it simpler to use Blender Curves and Edit Mode and Proportional editing.  Looping can be done with the Follow Path Constraint.  It appears you have very little graphical feedback compared to the Curve in edit mode in Blender. It seems like you are ignoring the useful features of Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some random points and use them as the handles of a spline as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

To generate another spline, just change the seed.